# Java 9 collections' convenience factory methods as an alternative to collection literals

Tags: java, collections, java-9

Consider this method (just for illustration):

```
boolean isSmallNumber(String s) {
    return (n in ["one", "two", "three", "four"]);
}
```

That, of course, is not *Java*, but it could be in your favourite alternative language that supports collection literals, such as *Groovy* or *Kotlin*. The expression is succinct, and, just like string literals, the compiler is allowed to put the collection literal in some static storage area(maybe even `"intern()"` it).

Now enter **Java 9**:

```
boolean isSmallNumber(String s) {
    return Set.of("one", "two", "three", "four").contains(s);
}
```

That's also succinct, but unfortunately it allocates a new Set on the heap every time you call it, and then immediately makes it available for garbage collection.

You can, of course, define a collection constant:

```
private static final Set<String> SMALL_NUMBERS = Set.of(...);
```

But then this definition could be a thousand lines away from the method definition in a large class, and you might not be able to think of a good descriptive name for it whereas a literal might be clearer (in this hypothetical case).

So, if I use `Set.of(...)` inside the method, will the **JIT** compiler optimize away the creation of a new object each time the method is called?

Comment: Just measure it.

Comment: since it does not escape the method, I am fairly sure it will. I think scalar replacement might even kick in for this...

Comment: I’d expect future JVMs to have additional optimizations addressing constant sets specifically. Until then, it would be possible to develop a tool to detect and handle them at byte code level to ensure the desired performance, without the need to alter the source code. Still, having a distance of “thousand lines” within one class sounds like code smell…

Comment: @Holger in general it's a code smell, but it happens all the time. Usually due to coding guidelines saying all constants should go at one section of a class (e.g. at the start or at the end). See, for example, method `newLine()` at PrintStream.java. It uses `if (autoFlush)` where `autoFlush` is about 500 lines away.

Comment: I would create a class which only responsibility would be to check whether the given number string is small. So the the proposed collection SMALL_NUMBERS would be next to the method and the class itself would be small. Example of encapsulation and SRP. Also it sounds like a premature optimization: is this method a bottleneck?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've crafted a simple JMH benchmark:

```
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
@State(Scope.Thread)
public class Temp {

    private Object value;

    @Setup
    public void setUp() {
        value = 50;
    }

    @Benchmark
    public boolean list1() {
        return List.of("one").contains(value);
    }

    @Benchmark
    public boolean list2() {
        return List.of("one", "two").contains(value);
    }

    @Benchmark
    public boolean list3() {
        return List.of("one", "two", "three").contains(value);
    }

    @Benchmark
    public boolean list4() {
        return List.of("one", "two", "three", "four").contains(value);
    }

    @Benchmark
    public boolean set1() {
        return Set.of("one").contains(value);
    }

    @Benchmark
    public boolean set2() {
        return Set.of("one", "two").contains(value);
    }

    @Benchmark
    public boolean set3() {
        return Set.of("one", "two", "three").contains(value);
    }

    @Benchmark
    public boolean set4() {
        return Set.of("one", "two", "three", "four").contains(value);
    }
}
```

After running the benchmark with `-prof gc`, I can make the following conclusion: JIT optimizes `list1`, `list2`, `set1`, `set2`, but not `list3`, `list4`, `set3`, `set4` <sup>[1]</sup>

This seems totally reasonable because for `N >= 3` `listN`/`setN` create more complex `List`/`Set` implementations than for `N <= 2`.

`List` implementation for 2 elements:

```
static final class List2<E> extends AbstractImmutableList<E> {
    private final E e0;
    private final E e1;
    ...
}
```

`List` implementation for 3 or more elements:

```
static final class ListN<E> extends AbstractImmutableList<E> {
    private final E[] elements;
    ...
}
```

`ListN` contains another level of indirection (an array) which apparently makes escape analysis much harder.

---

JMH output (slightly changed to fit the page):

```
Benchmark                  Mode  Cnt     Score      Error   Units
list1                      avgt    5     3,075 ?    1,165   ns/op
list1:·gc.alloc.rate       avgt    5     0,131 ?    1,117  MB/sec
list1:·gc.alloc.rate.norm  avgt    5    ? 10??               B/op
list1:·gc.count            avgt    5       ? 0             counts

list2                      avgt    5     3,161 ?    0,543   ns/op
list2:·gc.alloc.rate       avgt    5     0,494 ?    3,065  MB/sec
list2:·gc.alloc.rate.norm  avgt    5     0,001 ?    0,003    B/op
list2:·gc.count            avgt    5       ? 0             counts

list3                      avgt    5    33,094 ?    4,402   ns/op
list3:·gc.alloc.rate       avgt    5  6316,970 ?  750,240  MB/sec
list3:·gc.alloc.rate.norm  avgt    5    64,016 ?    0,089    B/op
list3:·gc.count            avgt    5   169,000             counts
list3:·gc.time             avgt    5   154,000                 ms

list4                      avgt    5    32,718 ?    3,657   ns/op
list4:·gc.alloc.rate       avgt    5  6403,487 ?  729,235  MB/sec
list4:·gc.alloc.rate.norm  avgt    5    64,004 ?    0,017    B/op
list4:·gc.count            avgt    5   165,000             counts
list4:·gc.time             avgt    5   146,000                 ms

set1                       avgt    5     3,218 ?    0,822   ns/op
set1:·gc.alloc.rate        avgt    5     0,237 ?    1,973  MB/sec
set1:·gc.alloc.rate.norm   avgt    5    ? 10??               B/op
set1:·gc.count             avgt    5       ? 0             counts

set2                       avgt    5     7,087 ?    2,029   ns/op
set2:·gc.alloc.rate        avgt    5     0,647 ?    4,755  MB/sec
set2:·gc.alloc.rate.norm   avgt    5     0,001 ?    0,010    B/op
set2:·gc.count             avgt    5       ? 0             counts

set3                       avgt    5    88,460 ?   16,834   ns/op
set3:·gc.alloc.rate        avgt    5  3565,506 ?  687,900  MB/sec
set3:·gc.alloc.rate.norm   avgt    5    96,000 ?    0,001    B/op
set3:·gc.count             avgt    5   143,000             counts
set3:·gc.time              avgt    5   108,000                 ms

set4                       avgt    5   118,652 ?   41,035   ns/op
set4:·gc.alloc.rate        avgt    5  2887,359 ?  920,180  MB/sec
set4:·gc.alloc.rate.norm   avgt    5   104,000 ?    0,001    B/op
set4:·gc.count             avgt    5   136,000             counts
set4:·gc.time              avgt    5    94,000                 ms
```

---

<sup>[1]</sup> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9+181, mixed mode)

Comment: @Holger Sure. See my update. `gc.count` is zero for `N <= 2` and non-zero for `N >= 3`. It is also interesting that `Set.contains` is slower than `List.contains`

Comment: That’s not so surprising. Hashing only pays off for sufficiently large sets, but since you’re also measuring the costs of constructing the set (hashing *all* values), it’s very unlikely to see `Set.of(values).contains(…)` being faster than `List.of(values).contains(…)`. That would change, if the JVM implements caching for these factory methods rather than just doing scalarization like any other temporary object.